# Correct method to check jQuery has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have noticed a couple of methods to check whether jQuery has loaded, I'm curious to know if one is better than the other, or, more reliable?

In the past I have used this to check if jQuery exists:

```
window.jQuery
```

But, here is another option, which checks to see if the object is defined:

```
typeof jQuery !== 'undefined'
```

Alternatively, is there an even better method than one of these two?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "better"?

Comment: is there a reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think voters understood what I was asking. Honestly don't understand why this was downvoted...

Both of my original suggestions do work, but, can't find any performance stats to suggest one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

im use this one

```
if ('undefined' == typeof window.jQuery) {
    // jquery not loaded
} else {
    // jquery is loaded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thats the recommended way of using jquery:

```
jQuery(function($) { //your stuff });
```

Look [here (jQuery documentation)](http://jQuery(function($)%20%7B%20//your%20stuff%20%7D);)